# What is the type for a function that takes a string and returns a string or takes void and returns void?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following function;

```
const capitalize = (input) =>
    (!(typeof input === 'undefined'))
        ? input
            .split(' ')
            .map(capitalizeWord)
            .join(' ')
        : undefined
```

This either takes a string and returns a string or takes undefined and returns undefined, but never takes a string and returns undefined or takes undefined and returns a string. My thought was the type should be something like `(void => void) & (string => string)` but that doesn't do at all what I want; Flow gets concerned that I haven't specified going into capitalize whether the input is a string or undefined, when what I want it to do is effectively dispatch to the correct type. When I let flow just infer the type, it infers `(void | string) => (string | void)`, which is too broad. What is the correct signature for this?

Comment: `(void | string) => (string | void)` seems correct to me. You accept a string or `undefined`, and return a string or `undefined`, so ...

Comment: Actually, it's `(input: any) => any`, but if you pass any `type`  except string you'll end with an error says `input.split is not a function` so it must be  `(input: string) => string`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) as `string` or `void`:

```
const capitalize = <T: string | void>(input: T): T =>
        (!(typeof input === 'undefined')) ? input
            .split(' ')
            .join(' ')
        : input
```

However, it should return passed arg, not `undefined`. [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1MghgA4CWWe0RAXgKagC8oAPACoBco2ATkWgOagA+oAG6wiAEwB8ACm4EArljZMAlEroTEoLdq1SAhFKwBPAlViRQshXVr0A5HLRiqkblTF3ly0AH5LaeSxNHRCtADoMAnIsKTtQT2DQnTCAK1E0WPjlRJC2KyCk0BRCEjJKKilvEFAwrFgAVQJTDgBhPAwKqrAiCzFYUABaSyw7aGhQDipI9DFQPDRQKg4OWA5EYuJScmopACIsKaxd5VqGpqW2jsqAbiA).

Comment: You can simplify a bit `<T: string|void>(input: T): T =>...`